# How to make such a Grid in antd

Tags: html, css, antd

How to make such a Grid in antd ? I have not found how to set the height of the first element to 2 lines.

```css
.container {  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 5px;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  grid-template-areas:
    "div1 div2"
    "div1 div3";
}

.div1 { grid-area: div1;     background-color:red ;}

.div2 { grid-area: div2;     background-color:blue ;}

.div3 { grid-area: div3;     background-color:green ;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="div1">1</div>
  <div class="div2">2</div>
  <div class="div3">3</div>
</div>
```

I did it this way. But I'm not sure that this is the right way.with this method, I can't set equal margins as in css grid.

```
        <Row>
            <Col span={16} >
                <img src={require('../../../../assets/images/img1.jpg')} alt=''/>
            </Col>
            <Col span={8}>
                <Row>
                    <Col>
                        <img src={require('../../../../assets/images/img1.jpg')} alt=''/>
                    </Col>
                    <Col>
                        <img src={require('../../../../assets/images/img1.jpg')} alt=''/>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </Col>
        </Row>
```

Comment: check : https://ant.design/components/grid/

Comment: @debugger I was watching. but I only found how to set the width of 1 element via span. But I didn't find about the height